# RAILS 5.2 + Ruby 2.6.3 + Capistrano + Puma + Nginx (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter)

Tags: ruby, puma, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have Rails application with below configuration

```
Rails: 5.2.0
Ruby: 6.2.3
Puma: 4.0
```

I set up a deployment strategy using `Capistrano`. I am able to deploy on the server using `Capistrano`. But I am facing one weird issue while starting up the puma server.

when I am starting the puma server I am getting this error `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter`

I re-checked the `database.yml` file adapter is specified correctly and also no alignment issue with `yml` file.

here is the log which I get while starting the puma server

```
[9141] ! Unable to load application: ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database 
configuration does not specify adapter
bundler: failed to load command: puma 
(/var/www/xxxxx/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
/var/www/xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:184:in `spec'
```

**Puma.rb**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env puma

    directory '/var/www/xxxx/current'
    rackup "/var/www/xxxx/current/config.ru"
    environment 'dev'

    tag ''

    pidfile "/var/www/xxxx/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
    state_path "/var/www/xxxx/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
    stdout_redirect '/var/www/xxxx/current/log/puma.access.log', '/var/www/xxxx/current/log/puma.error.log', true

    threads 4,16

    app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
    shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

    bind 'unix:///var/www/xxxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma_xxxx.sock'

    workers 1

    restart_command 'bundle exec puma'


    preload_app!


    on_restart do
      puts 'Refreshing Gemfile'
      ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/var/www/xxxx/current/Gemfile"
    end


    before_fork do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
    end

    on_worker_boot do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
      end
    end
```

I assume that there might be an issue of worker when it is trying to connect with database. So I changed my `puma.rb` which I found on other documents.

**Updated puma.rb**

```
  #!/usr/bin/env puma

  # Change to match your CPU core count
  workers 1

  # Min and Max threads per worker
  #threads 1, 6

  app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
  shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

  # Default to production
  rails_env = "dev"
  environment rails_env

  # Set up socket location
  bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/tmp/sockets/puma_xxx.sock"


  # Set master PID and state locations
  pidfile "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
  state_path "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
  stdout_redirect '/var/www/xxx/current/log/puma.access.log', '/var/www/xxx/current/log/puma.error.log', true
  activate_control_app

  on_worker_boot do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
  end
```

after making changes in the `puma.rb` file puma get started, but when I hit on browser with the domain name there is a blank page comming. I check nginx error log I found that there is some time out issue.

**Error stacktrace**

```
2020/08/05 12:49:10 [error] 20295#0: *9802 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: xxxx, request: "GET /s3.xxxx.org/image001.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/www/xxxx/shared/tmp/sockets/puma_xxxx.sock/s3.xxxx.org/image001.png", host: "xxxx", referrer: "https://xxxx/"
```

Command which I used to start the puma serve `bundle exec puma -C /var/www/xxx/shared/puma.rb`

Any more information is required let me know I will update my question accordingly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share the database.yml?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing to find the configuration for db. I had the same issue when I was trying to use primary and read replica.

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection()` expects either a hash contain configuration or you can symbol of environment. (Documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class)

I solved it by passing `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env.to_sym)` and I have this on config/database.yml

```
database.yml

development:
  primary:
    host: somevalue
    username: somevalue
    password: somevalue
  primary_replica:
    host: somevalue
    username: somevalue
    password: somevalue
    replica: true
```